# Why does the 'const' qualifier on return type have no effect on functions that are marked with __forceinline/inline?

Tags: c++, clang

I'm compiling my C++ code with clang, and am wondering the meaning behind the compiler error:

`error : 'const' type qualifier on return type has no effect`

The following syntax generates the error:

`inline const int foo();`

`__forceinline const bool bar();`

Comment: What effect do you expect `const` to have, in this context?

Comment: Did you try removing `inline`? I get exact same warning even without `inline`. [Example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/roZ3TnzhHws0WogK).

Comment: Why would you ever return a `const int`? The integer can always be stored into a non-const variable and be modified. It's a by-value return type after all.. `const` may be valid there, syntactically, but it makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does the 'const' qualifier on return type have no effect ...

Because the function returns a prvalue. There is no difference between const and nonconst prvalues of type `int` or `bool`. The qualifier only makes a difference to prvalues of class types (even then, returning a const value would be quite unconventional).

The compiler is being helpful and warns you about this. It is likely that a mistake was made when writing that declaration because meaningless qualifiers are not useful. Who-ever wrote it may have intended to write something else that would have had meaning.

Evidently, the compiler has been told to treat warnings as errors.

> ... on functions that are marked with __forceinline/inline?

The same applies to functions that are not marked with those.

Answer (score 5):

This is actually a warning, that is promoted to error by a command line switch. It is not related to `inline` or `__forceinline` and is pretty self-explanatory.

`const` and `volatile` qualifiers of function return types, *when the function returns by value*, have no meaning because conceptually the returned value is either discarded or used as a temporary for initialization of an object on the caller's side. `const`/`volatile` qualification of that object is in the caller's jurisdiction. For example, it is perfectly legal to initialize a mutable `int` variable from a function call that returns `const int`.